# Windows 2000 can't connect to Samba 4.5 share: System error 1326

Tags: samba, windows-2000

There is a Windows 2000 Professional based VM that wants to map a network drive. The network share is being served from a Linux machine that has Samba 4.5 installed and configured.

Although access from Windows 10 works fine, Windows 2000 repeatedly asks for a user / password combination and wouldn't even show the available shares, printers etc.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the following lines in the Samba configuration file are needed.

```
[global]
lanman auth=yes
ntlm auth=yes
```

**WARNING**: These settings pose a big security risk. The Samba server will use older and **unsafe** protocols. It's possible that passwords will fly unencrypted over your network, your network shares will become an easy target for hackers etc.

Comment: A security risk indeed. Perhaps better NOT to use outdated and unsupported OSes?

Comment: I fully agree. Weak excuse: this VM is only there to be able to use ancient hardware not supported anymore on recent Windows versions.
I'm going to SCP the files created inside the VM to the file server instead. At least I don't have to expose the Samba server that much then...

Comment: Chances are that hardware is still supported in current user-friendly Linux distros like Ubuntu and derivatives...